# Builder and Abstract Factory patterns UML diagram with examples

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder, abstract-factory

So I'm making a presentation about `Builder` and `Abstract Factory` design patterns.

Would you say that this is an accurate representation of the UML diagrams with examples?

**Builder UML:**

[image]

**1.** Can the Director class only specify what is the order of steps that the Builder will follow, or can we also omit some steps that are not necessary for the object that we are making?

-
**`Abstract Factory UML:`**
[image]

**2.** Can someone explain the relation of the Abstract Product with the rest of the diagram?

For example:

**3.** Can we know what type of abstract product will be built (PoloWheels or GolfWheels) and if we can specify them, do we do it in the client or the abstract factory?

**4.** And is the Abstract Product (Seats/Wheels) the final object, or is the final object created from the Abstract Product?

Most of the things are from [Refactoring.guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder/java/example#example-0) but I don't want to simply copy and paste the image and call it a day.

(I'm trying to learn a lot in a short time, so maybe some questions are bad and make no sense but it's the process of learning.)